# How to show Time Remaining when playing a song in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, xcode, avaudioplayer

I use AVAudioPlayer to play an mp3 file to a user within my iPhone app. This all works fine and dandy. I even update a PLAY/PAUSED button depending on the state of the player. But it would be nice to know how much longer the song will play.

So How do I show the time remaining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up an NSTimer and compute `audioPlayer.duration - audioPlayer.currentTime` while playing.